# Adding autonumber column to php table that reads from mysql

Tags: php, sql, auto-increment

I am trying to add a column before my first column that starts numbering each record, starting from 1. I was trying to add autoincrement to this line    **echo "" . $row['ss'] . "";**, but that does not seem to want to work. Any ideas how to do this?

My code looks like this:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `results` WHERE Event='100' AND Gender='M' ORDER BY Performance ASC");

echo "<table border='0'>
<tr>
<th align='left'>Pos</th>
<th align='left'>Event</th>
<th>Performance</th>
<th>Wind</th>
<th>Place</th>
<th align='left'>Name</th>
<th align='left'>Surname</th>
<th>Age</th>
<th>Team</th>
<th>Meet</th>
<th>Date</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['ss'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Event'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Performance'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Wind'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Pos'] . "</td>";
echo "<td width='100' align='left'>" . $row['Surname'] . "</td>";
echo "<td Width='100'>" . $row['Name'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Age'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Team'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Meet'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Date'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line in header

```
<th align='left'>#</th>
```

And here php code

```
$count = 1;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $count . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['ss'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Event'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Performance'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Wind'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Pos'] . "</td>";
echo "<td width='100' align='left'>" . $row['Surname'] . "</td>";
echo "<td Width='100'>" . $row['Name'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Age'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Team'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Meet'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Date'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
//other code
$count=$count+1;
}
```

Comment: Please mark it as answer if you think it helped you

Comment: Thank you. I am getting the numbers for each record, but the data from the columns to its right does not display. I am not 100% sure where to enter the code you supplied. Could you possibly indicate that to me?

Answer (score 0):

A better solution would be to use a variable counter to "number" your rows:

```
$counter = 1;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
   echo "<td>" . $counter . "</td>";
   $counter++;
}
```

This is the right way to do it since if that `ss` column is the mysql auto increment, then your rows will not be numbered by the `SORT` but rather from the order in which they were inserted into the database regardless of any sorting you apply.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change **fetch_array** with **fetch_assoc**